# Where are cv::Mat constructors explicitly defined?

Tags: c++, opencv

[1] Where are the cv::Mat data structure constructors explicitly (in C/C++) defined in the OpenCV source code?

I assume a cv::Mat data structure is dynamically allocated to the heap when something like

`cv::Mat mat(rows, cols, type);`

is called, but could neither find the ANSI C or C++ implementation in

`opencv / modules / core / src / matrix.cpp` nor in

`opencv / modules / core / src / datastructs.cpp`.

**SOLVED:** `cv::Mat` is allocated with a `fastMalloc()` in [matrix.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L183).  this is performed within the `cv::Mat:create()` [function](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-create).

[2] Further, I'm curious to know where in hardware the cv::Mat will be located when image processing operations are performed:

. always in 'main memory' (SDRAM),

. always in on-chip caches (SRAM),

. or some combination of the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cv::Mat mat(rows, cols, type);

This is inline constructor and it's implemented in `core/mat.hpp`:

```
inline Mat::Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type) : size(&rows)
{
    initEmpty();
    create(_rows, _cols, _type);
}
```

Comment: and create() is defined where?  I suppose I'm really looking for the point where OpenCV types/functions are implemented in ANSI C types/functions.

Comment: @sixstring91 in the same file. Press `ctrl+f` in your editor.

Comment: i only find declarations of `cv::Mat::create()` which are defined in terms of `create()` in `mat.hpp`.  however, i ended up finding the explicit declaration of `Mat::create()` in `matrix.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

The actual constructors are in

... / core / core.hpp

```
class CV_EXPORTS Mat
{
public:
    //! default constructor
    Mat();
    //! constructs 2D matrix of the specified size and type
    // (_type is CV_8UC1, CV_64FC3, CV_32SC(12) etc.)
    Mat(int rows, int cols, int type);
    Mat(Size size, int type);
    //! constucts 2D matrix and fills it with the specified value _s.
    Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, const Scalar& s);
    Mat(Size size, int type, const Scalar& s);

    //! constructs n-dimensional matrix
    Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type);
    Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type, const Scalar& s);

    //! copy constructor
    Mat(const Mat& m);
    //! constructor for matrix headers pointing to user-allocated data
    Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP);
    Mat(Size size, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP);
    Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type, void* data, const size_t* steps=0);
 .....

};
```

Comment: link please. I have looked in the core.hpp and couldn't find the code you posted https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp

Comment: It's actually in core/mat.hpp: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp